# usb drive recovery: TestDisk/PhotoRec detects USB name and size, but can't recover data

Tags: usb, data-recovery

I have a USB drive that I have been unable to access. When I plug it in to my Windows computer, the icon for the drive on My PC flickers, like it keeps disconnecting and reconnecting, and sometimes the "choose what to do with this drive" notification pops up for a second. When I plug it in to my Ubuntu Linux machine, it shows up as a `/dev/sd*` file but not mounted in `/media`.
When I run TestDisk on either of those machines, the USB drive is detected with the correct name and size, and it shows up as read-only. However, when I try to search for partitions, it can't find any, and when I try to recover files with photorec, it can't find any files. I also tried ddrescue and kept getting read errors. Is my USB toast?

Edit 1: Something else I notices is that when I try `lsusb` the USB drive shows up, but at the wrong size.

Comment: Hmm I also noticed that the drive gets a bit warm after being plugged in

Comment: Does ddrescue consistently report errors at the same location or are they more sporadic? If they're sporadic, I believe ddrescue has the option of running multiple times to try and "fill in the gaps" from previous runs on each pass?

Comment: @NeilCoffey It consistently reports errors everywhere. The error rate is the same as the read rate.

Answer (score 0):

Your story about connect and reconnect suggests three possible causes:

1. Power supply problems (details on the connection setup missing, components, start-up behaviour)
2. USB connection problems (to exclude this type of error replace cabling, use a different machine)
3. broken drive

As for 1. and 2. you did not deliver sufficient information.

> I also tried ddrescue and kept getting read errors.

This sentences does not express anything meaningful. Getting read errors with broken drives did not prevent me from recovering drive content. You should rather post your ddrescue log file which would be the next logical step after exluding type 1 and type 2 failures. Looking across the postings at the forum at cgsecurity.org will show you lots of examples what information might be useful for you to post.

11.2.2021 19:33 CET:
Taken into account the additional infromation of ddrescue providing zero rescued bytes (hopefully have let that run some hours at least) I would recommend stopping the copy attempt and contacting a professional recovery service.

Comment: Sorry for being so vague; I have exclude a type 1 or 2 error. And by ddrescue getting read errors, I mean that the read error rate is the same as the reading rate, the "rescued" value never goes above 0B, and everything it scanned is labeled "bad-sector".
I haven't actually quite finished ddrescue yet, I'll post the log when it's done.